# How to get the user details using google-plus-api-integration with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, api, google-plus

Hi kindly check this git hub link
 https://github.com/samwierema/google-plus-api-codeigniter I have downloade this and put it in my folder and I have created client id and other details. but I don't know how I can get the user details. Here is my controller

```
function glogin()
        {
           $this->load->library('googleplus');    
           $userProfile = $this->googleplus->people->get('me'); // when authorized
          // $userProfile = $this->googleplus->people->get('115414977082318263605');
            print("<pre>");
            print_r($userProfile); 
            exit;
        }
```

get('115414977082318263605') will return user details. but how I get the user id

please help me to figure out this problem

Thank you

Comment: What print_r($userProfile);  returns you  ?

Comment: nothing. but the next line $userProfile = $this->googleplus->people->get('115414977082318263605'); is returning details

Comment: Try with my code what is gives you ?

Comment: What process you are following to get `$userProfile = $this->googleplus->people->get('me');` ??

Comment: in between i have to add some code to get the user id. I dont know what code i have to use

Comment: and I have to add user id instead of me

Comment: Read and follow http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-google-oauth-php/

Comment: but the demo itself is not working